# How to go about finding a professional moving company for rack hardware

Tags: migration, colocation

My company will be moving an entire rack of server hardware from a colo facility in Seattle to anot the Silicon Valley area. We are trying to figure out if we should do it ourselves or hire an external company for that. I googled around a bit but could only find cookie cutter sites by what seems to be the same domain name squatter. How would you or how did you go about finding a reliable moving company for this kind of project?

Recommendations of specific companies would be welcome if made by an unaffiliated party but I am afraid they're against the rules here (this is my first question on SF).

Comment: Road Trip!  (i.e. do it yourself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to note: do NOT move the rack and its contents as a unit! You need to take the servers out, and wrap them in some thick blankets for shock absorption (I suppose you can leave your UPSes in if they're at the bottom of the rack to keep the center of gravity low, so the rack itself won't tip over while being moved). Stacking the servers shouldn't be problematic, as long as they don't fall over, of course.

Aside from that, it might be worth asking the company if they've had experience moving IT hardware or other large/valuable/delicate items. Your facilities manager may be able to help picking out a specific company.

Answer (score 4):

Ask the site manager för recommendations.

Comment: Nïce answer! ;-)

Comment: Actually, it's "für" ...

Answer (score 2):

Most moving companies will/can do this.  Talk to several. Get a feeling for how well that can handle it.  Work with the during pack up.  You will want to unrack it all prior to shipment